# Getting code coverage reports with Cypress and React app

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am working on a project given to me by a client with an existing code base. It is React based, without using Create-React-App. I'm not the most versed in using babel and webpack at all, as I typically rely on CRA and react-scripts. I'm using Cypress with Istanbul for unit testing, and after following the docs and several guides I have been unable to get code coverage reports to generate.

I am not entirely sure what code would be necessary for anyone looking to help, so I will put what I think is relevant here and add as recommended by anyone commenting.

My babelrc file:

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      },
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": [
          "./src"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ],
    [
      "transform-class-properties"
    ],
    [
      "istanbul"
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "istanbul"
      ]
    },
    "e2e": {
      "plugins": [
        "istanbul"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

index.js of cypress plugins:

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
  on('file:preprocessor', require('@cypress/code-coverage/use-babelrc'))
  return config
}
```

index.js of my support folder for Cypress:

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

And the script I execute for testing

```
 "cy": "cypress run && nyc report --reporter=text --reporter=text-summary"
```

Everything was instrumented by NYC, as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the end I wound up figuring out that I didn't have NYC installed as a dependency somehow. In addition to that, my package.json did not include the following line:
` "nyc": { "all": true, "include": "src/*.js" }`

After adding this, it worked perfectly.